# Wrap-around Grid Errors- Subtraction only?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on a program that picks a random location in a grid, checks its neighbors, and assigns the location the value of 1 if any of the neighbors are occupied. If none are occupied, the program picks a random neighbor and moves to it (switch case in diffuse()).

```
public class Frost {
int width;
int height;
int density;
int seed;
int[][] grid = new int[this.width][this.height];
Random randoma = new Random();
```

[Later...]

```
boolean diffuse(){
    int steps = 0;
    int diffusionSteps = this.height*this.width*2;
    int indexA = (int) randoma.nextInt(width);
    int indexB = (int) randoma.nextInt(height);
    while (steps <= diffusionSteps)
    {
    if (grid[indexA][indexB] == 0) { //if empty
           if (this.checkNorth(indexA, indexB) || this.checkSouth(indexA,indexB) || this.checkEast(indexA,indexB) || this.checkWest(indexA,indexB))
            {
                grid[indexA][indexB] = 1;
                        return true;
                    }
           else {
            steps++; //increase counter before moving and looping again
            int ofFour = this.randoma.nextInt(4);
        int tempA = indexA;
        int tempB = indexB;
                                switch(ofFour)
                                    {
                                    case 1:
                                        if (tempA+1 >= this.width)
                        indexA = (tempA+1)%this.width;
                    else indexA=tempA+1;

                                    case 2:
                                        if(tempB+1 >= this.height)
                        indexB = (tempB+1)%this.height;
                    else indexB = tempB+1;

                                    case 3:
                                        if ((tempB-1) <= 0)
                        indexB = (indexB-1)%this.height;
                    else indexB = tempB-1;

                                    case 4:
                                        if ((tempA-1) <= 0)
                        indexA = (tempA-1)%this.width;
                    else indexA = tempA-1;

                                     }
                         }
                }

    }
    if (steps>=diffusionSteps){
        grid[indexA][indexB]=1;
        return true;
        }
return false;
}
```

I'm getting ArrayIndexOutofBounds: -1 errors for getSouth and getWest methods. I thought the problem might be the decrement operators, but I fiddled with them and nothing changed. Any insights would be appreciated.

```
boolean checkSouth(int indexA, int indexB)
{
--indexB;
if (indexB > 0)
    {return grid[indexA][indexB-1] == 1;}
    else    
    return grid[indexA][((indexB-1)%this.height)] == 1;
}


boolean checkWest(int indexA, int indexB)
{
    --indexA;
    if (indexA > 0)
        return grid[indexA][indexB-1] == 1;
    else
        return grid[(indexA)%this.width][indexB] == 1;
}
```

Comment: Paste the grid, so we can make some test with your same data. Or at least add `checkNorth`, `checkEast` and `randoma`

Comment: @Luigi Cortese The grid is an array of int arrays that defaults to 256 by 256. I can't think of a way to include the code for the grid without copying the whole class, which I can if that would be helpful.

Comment: go just for the three missing elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the way you do modulo: if `index` is `-1`, then `index % height` will still be `-1`.

You need to do `(index + height) % height` to deal with the negative number (provided you want the grid to be cyclic).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here

```
boolean checkSouth(int indexA, int indexB) {
    System.out.println(indexA+" "+indexB);
    --indexB;
    if (indexB > 0) {
        return grid[indexA][indexB - 1] == 1;
    } else
        return grid[indexA][((indexB - 1) % this.height)] == 1;
}
```

When it's executed with `indexB` equal to 1. In this case it is first decremented

```
--indexB;  //now it's equal to 0
```

and then here

```
(indexB - 1) % this.height
```

the result is -1, and being it used as index for an array... well, out of bounds!